# How to pass file array as Intent result

Tags: android, file, sockets, android-intent, arraylist

I'm trying to receive an `ArrayList<String>` containing selected file paths from another activity. At receiving activity, I'm using those file paths to construct file objects which can be transmitted over standard Java sockets. The file paths are received successfully (a dialog shows all the selected paths correctly), but I'm unable to create file objects in `MainActivity` (or at least this is what I think so. The socket connections get timed out). The hard coded file paths works fine (those files are successfully transmitted over Java sockets). Any suggestion please? Here is what I've done so far:

`MainActivity` code snippet:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent launchFileManager = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                FileChooserActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(launchFileManager, REQUEST_CODE); //receives files
        //fileArray has been populated with selected files

        Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initializeServer();
                if (!fileArray.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        copyFile(fileArray.get(i), fileArray.get(i).getName());
                }
            }
        });
        trd.start();

        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dispFilesid);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);
                ListView mlv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglistviewid);
                ArrayAdapter<String> daa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filepathNameArray);
                mlv.setAdapter(daa);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                filepathNameArray = data.getExtras().getStringArrayList("key");// file URI received
                for(int f=0;f<filepathNameArray.size();f++){
                    String buildPath=filepathNameArray.get(f);
                    buildPath=buildPath.replace("/storage/sdcard0", "");
                    File tempFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), buildPath);
                    fileArray.add(tempFile); //create file array
                }
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast cancelToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                cancelToast.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT1: Hard coded file paths:

```
final File file1=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/airdrive/Xperia.pdf");
    final File file2=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/airdrive/Expedition.pdf");
    final File file3=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/airdrive/Conspiracy.pdf");
    final File file4=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/airdrive/Robinson.pdf");
    final File file5=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/airdrive/Sphere.pdf");

    fileArray.add(file1);
    fileArray.add(file2);
    fileArray.add(file3);
    fileArray.add(file4);
    fileArray.add(file5);
```

Format of string `Filepath`s received from `SecondActivity`:

```
"/storage/sdcard0/Videos/myvid1.mp4"
"/storage/sdcard0/Videos/myvid2.mp4"
"/storage/sdcard0/Videos/myvid3.mp4"
"/storage/sdcard0/Videos/myvid4.mp4"
```

Comment: compare your hardcoded path with the path you are getting , if possible paste it here !!

Comment: Please refer to my edit section.